# Using a Cloud Storage Integration to copy data from Blob in a different Azure region than Snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm in Azure US-East and I have a Snowflake instance in Azure US-East-2. I've setup a [Cloud Storage Integration](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html#step-1-create-a-cloud-storage-integration-in-snowflake), and I've verified that the Service Principal has the appropriate permissions to access my Storage Account, which is configured with strict firewall rules (cannot be accessed via the internet).

Per the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html), I should simply whitelist Snowflake's VNet, which could be provided to me by Snowflake Support, however whitelisting VNets across Azure regions does not work.

So, how do I copy data into Snowflake when the Blob is located in a different Azure region? Is peering the solution? Private link?

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head that the problem stems from your Snowflake account being in a different region than your storage account. I am not sure that peering (PrivateLink or not) is supported. Might be worth a Snowflake Support case and I'd also loop in Microsoft for an extra pair of eyes.